# ExtJS Xml reader error message

Tags: xml, extjs

Upon uploading a file with Ext.form.action.Submit(), I get the return result in XML.

```
<KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
<key>true</key>
<value>path/to/filename.ext</value>
</KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring>
```

So I tried

```
form.errorReader = Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Xml', {
    success: 'key',
    file : 'value'
});
```

The error message states an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` in Reader.js

Any ideas how to change the XmlReader that it accepts aforementioned Xml format and provides success and file values?

EDIT:

I built the errorReader in such a way that no more js error is raised. But still I don't find how to access the  in my success handler.

```
form.errorReader = Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Xml', {
    record : 'KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring',
    success: 'key',
    result: 'value',
    model: {
        prototype: {
            fields:['value']
        }
    }
});
```

and success:

```
success: function(fp, o) {
    alert(o.result); // object object
    alert(Object.keys(o.result).join(',')); // success,errors
    Ext.getCmp("companyLogo").setSrc=o.result; // does nothing
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.response.responseXml + '" on the server'); // undefined
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you are getting your xml back in particular.  However, the reader was able to parse the xml in my example below.  Here is my working code, I console.log() the data parsed.

```
var xml = '<KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"><key>true</key><value>path/to/filename.ext</value></KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring>';
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
        Ext.define('MyModel', {
            extend:'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'key',
                type:'auto'
            }, {
                name: 'value',
                type:'auto'
            }]
        });
        var s = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            data: doc,
            model:'MyModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'KeyValuePairOfbooleanstring'
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(s.data.items[0].data);
```

Comment: I don't need a reader for a store. I need the reader to return sth like "success:true", if <key>true</key>, or "success:false", if <key>false</key>. Which your example does not, and I don't know how to add, sorry. Also, my xml does not have multiple records, just one single value to return, which is in the <value> tag.